# Mindstorms IR Sensor Measurement compatibility issue

Tags: labview, lego-mindstorms

I am using Mindstorms and build a Robot with two Motors and a IR Sensor.
1) I made a program which lets the Robot follow a IR signal and stops when reaching it.
2) I made a program to remote control the robot with the IR control.
Both program work. But when combining them, program 1 does not work anymore.

It gives eratic results from the IR sensor. It seams the detecting a IR-Button is not compatible with measuring the signal in the same program. Anyone has similar experiance or know how to deal with it?

This is the program which works:
[image]

Introducing another Selection around it which senses a IR Button does not work anymore:
[image]
[image]
The result is, that the program follows to the right section, but the IR measurements of distance and directions give random results.
Anyone has any Idea?

Comment: I don't have an answer (other than maybe use 2 IR sensors if you have them), but I think your guess as to why this isn't working is a good one. Since you are using two different "modes" of the IR sensor, each switch block causes the IR sensor to reconfigure itself into a different mode. It would not surprise me at all if the sensor was missing data because it only has once chance to read data before it switches modes again.

Comment: I fear that you are correct David Lechner . I now tried to use a separate sensor block before the if-statement hoping it would initialize the sensor again, but no chance. It looks to me like a bug. The system has to regognize the first appearance of a sensor read out anyway in order to initialize the sensor. So it should detect if the mode is changed and initialize it again. Of coarse that might slow down things a bit. Or another solution would be to have an init block for the IR sensor. Wolfgang.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried another sensor and there is still a problem it could possibly be a bug with the software. I would post your example on the the NI MINDSTORMS support board so that they can look into the bug.

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW-for-LEGO-MINDSTORMS-and/bd-p/460